# Word for "personal reason for not being able to do something"

Tags: single-word-requests

If a person wants to do something but he is not able to do that due to some personal reason, what is the exact word for that reason?

Comment: .... an excuse?

Comment: I think this is "not constructive". If I want to fly to the moon, am I constrained by my *personal* lack of wings, or by the "external, real-world fact" that there wouldn't be enough air to flap against once I got a few miles up?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "personal reason." Do they hold moral reservations, like a conscientious objector?  Maybe it's a physical limitation, or lack of sufficient talent.  Or maybe it's a schedule conflict.  Or maybe something like parental duty limits their freedom.

Answer (score 3):

That reason could possibly be called an ["obligation":](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obligation?s=t)

> something by which a person is bound or obliged to do certain things, and which arises out of a sense of duty or results from custom, law, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Limitation* might work. One of its definitions is "the extent of one's capacity or a constraint that stops something." It could be a physical limitation, a mental limitation, or a scheduling limitation. An example sentence in [this dictionary definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/limitation) is: He knows his limitations as a writer.